# How do I get the first timestamp (index) of a group when applying groupby to a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, timestamp

My data in principle looks like this:

```
                            one  two
timestamp                           
2013-12-06 00:00:01.200000    1    1
2013-12-06 00:00:02.200000    1    2
2013-12-06 00:00:03.200000    2    1
2013-12-06 00:00:04.200000    3    5
2013-12-06 00:00:05.200000    1    2
```

I would like to group it over column 'one' and take the first timestamp of each group.
Applying this to column 'two' works just fine but it does not work for the timestamp.

```
df_2 = df['two'].groupby(df['one']).first()
```

gives:

```
one
1      1
2      1
3      5
```

but it tells me there is no attribute 'first' when I apply the same thing to the index.

```
df_3 = df.index.groupby(df['one']).first()
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `groupby/apply`:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('one')
>>> grouped.apply(lambda x: x.index[0])
one
1     2013-12-06 00:00:01.200000
2     2013-12-06 00:00:03.200000
3     2013-12-06 00:00:04.200000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

By the way,

```
df_2 = df['two'].groupby(df['one']).first()
```

can also be expressed as

```
>>> grouped['two'].first()
one
1      1
2      1
3      5
Name: two, dtype: int64
```